# node does not recognize the r exe startup path

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use the r-integration package in node,

on my environment "PATH" variable I have the path to r

C:\apps\R-3.6.2\bin\x64;

for IT reasons I cannot install r to the program files.

when i run this in node

```
const R = require('r-integration');

let result = R.executeRCommand("max(1,2,3)");
console.log(result);
```

I get an error

Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Program Files\R'

Is there a way to make this work with the current r path?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that there's not much you can do other than moving `R` into the program files directory. If you take a look at the [source-code](https://github.com/FabrizioSandri/r-integration/blob/master/src/R.js#L59), the path is hardcoded:

```
if (fs.lstatSync("C:\\Program Files\\R").isDirectory()){
    // Rscript is installed, let's find the path (verison problems)
    installationDir = "C:\\Program Files\\R";
```

You could of course fork the repoistory and change the code to allow a custom path or even better - create a pull-request in order to make the directory configurable.

Comment: @A Aa: any feedback? You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers